# Calculations with dplyr based on specific factors and dates and summaries of values

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, summarize

I have a data frame of counts of different classifications of ship on specific dates at certain distances off shore (DOS), e.g. 0-12nm and 0-100nm - I would like to subtract the ships within the 0-12nm DOS from 0-100nm, so that I can calculate how many e.g. "passenger" ships were only in 12-100nm on each date. Once that is complete i would like to how many total passenger, cargo etc ships were counted within each DOS for the total time period... I can work out a really laborious ways to do this, but I am pretty sure with the mutate and summarize functions in dplyr there is a more efficient way to run this...

here is an dummy data frame:

```
df<- structure(list(date = structure(c(17622, 17623, 17624, 17625, 
17626, 17627, 17622, 17623, 17624, 17625, 17626, 17627), class = "Date"), 
    `Passenger(6X)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Cargo(7X)` = c(2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 4), `Tanker(8X)` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0), Otherb = c(`5` = 0, `6` = 0, 
    `7` = 0, `8` = 0, `9` = 0, `10` = 0, `144` = 0, `154` = 0, 
    `164` = 0, `174` = 0, `184` = 0, `194` = 0), DOS = c("0-12nm", 
    "0-12nm", "0-12nm", "0-12nm", "0-12nm", "0-12nm", "0-100nm", 
    "0-100nm", "0-100nm", "0-100nm", "0-100nm", "0-100nm")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1454L, 1455L, 1456L, 1457L, 1458L, 1459L))
```

In this example on the 1st of April 2018 cargo ships in 12-100nm should be 3 - the output could be in the form of new columns etc. ... within my real data set i actually have 4 different distances offshore and over a year of dates.... so I think dplyr is the best way to go for this - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
df %>% 
       group_by(date) %>% 
       summarise_at(
          vars(`Cargo(7X)`, `Tanker(8x)`), 
          funs(.[DOS == '0-100nm'] - .[DOS == '0-12nm'])
    )

#   date       `Cargo(7X)`  `Tanker(8x)`
# 1 2018-04-01           3            0
# 2 2018-04-02           4            3
# 3 2018-04-03           5            1
# 4 2018-04-04           4            0
# 5 2018-04-05           5            1
# 6 2018-04-06           1            0
```

**Option 2 :**

```
df %>% 
   group_by(date, DOS) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(`Cargo(7X)`, `Tanker(8x)`), funs(sum)) %>% 
   gather(-(date:DOS), key = Ship, value = Value) %>%
   spread(key = DOS, value = Value) %>% 
   mutate('12-100nm' = `0-100nm`- `0-12nm`)

#    date       Ship       `0-100nm` `0-12nm` `12-100nm`
#  1 2018-04-01 Cargo(7X)          5        2          3
#  2 2018-04-01 Tanker(8X)         0        0          0
#  3 2018-04-02 Cargo(7X)          4        0          4
#  4 2018-04-02 Tanker(8X)         3        0          3
#  5 2018-04-03 Cargo(7X)          7        2          5
#  6 2018-04-03 Tanker(8X)         1        0          1
#  7 2018-04-04 Cargo(7X)          6        2          4
#  8 2018-04-04 Tanker(8X)         0        0          0
#  9 2018-04-05 Cargo(7X)          7        2          5
# 10 2018-04-05 Tanker(8X)         1        0          1
# 11 2018-04-06 Cargo(7X)          4        3          1
# 12 2018-04-06 Tanker(8X)         0        0          0
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response - i am struggling to get the option two to run - however i like the output it gives. I am getting the error message Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'Cargo(7X)' not found - which i think is coming from the spread function component - can you explain that a little more?

Comment: you're right; I made a mistake on the spread, it would work with `spread(key = DOS, value = Value)`.

Comment: Ok, awesome - thank you. Now if i have multiple DOS ranges e.g. 0-12, 0-50 as well as 0-100 is there a way to incorporate that? to get 12-50 and then 50-100 or would i need to just split the data and produce one output for each range? (does that make sense?).

Comment: you can make several operations in the mutate, for instance `12-50 = 0-50 - 0-12`, `50-100 = 0-100 - 0-50`

Comment: Amazing - thank you so much for you input that works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you should be able to use `dplyr` to get that.
`diff` field in the below example:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Total = `Passenger(6X)` + `Cargo(7X)` + `Tanker(8X)` + `Otherb`) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(diff = ifelse(row_number() == 1, Total, Total - lag(Total)))
   date       `Passenger(6X)` `Cargo(7X)` `Tanker(8X)` Otherb DOS     Total  diff
   <date>               <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2018-04-01               0           2            0      0 0-12nm      2     2
 2 2018-04-02               0           0            0      0 0-12nm      0     0
 3 2018-04-03               0           2            0      0 0-12nm      2     2
 4 2018-04-04               0           2            0      0 0-12nm      2     2
 5 2018-04-05               0           2            0      0 0-12nm      2     2
 6 2018-04-06               0           3            0      0 0-12nm      3     3
 7 2018-04-01               0           5            0      0 0-100nm     5     3
 8 2018-04-02               0           4            3      0 0-100nm     7     7
 9 2018-04-03               0           7            1      0 0-100nm     8     6
10 2018-04-04               0           6            0      0 0-100nm     6     4
11 2018-04-05               0           7            1      0 0-100nm     8     6
12 2018-04-06               0           4            0      0 0-100nm     4     1
```